# What is refinement of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

We call an  oriented graph $G$ is a triple $G = (V, E, i)$, where $V$ is a finite
set $V = \{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ whose elements are called vertex and $E$ is a finite set whose
elements are called edges and a map $i: E \rightarrow V \times V$ with $i(e) = \{e^−, e^+\}$, where $e^−$ is the origin of the edge $e$ and $e^+$ is the end of the edge $e$.

The edge refinement of an oriented graph $G = (V, E, i)$ is the
graph $G_E = (V \coprod V_E; E \coprod E, i_E)$ with a point added at each edge as a degree $2$
vertex, where $V_E$ denotes the set of this vertices. The set of vertices of $G_E$ is
$V \coprod V_E$ and the set of edges is $E \coprod E$. The incidence relation is described by map $i_E : E \coprod E \rightarrow V \times V_E$ because each edge of $G_E$ connects exactly one vertex of
$V$ to a vertex of $V_E$ and an edge of $G_E$ is called a half-edge.

Actually I cannot understand the "refinement of a  graph". Since each loop contribute to the degree of a vertex $2$. Are we actually adding a loop in each vertex to the main graph?  Am I correct?

Comment: No, it splits each edge in two "half-edges" by adding a vertex in the middle of it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks. I  have one more confusion, that is why we write the set of vertices of $G_E$ is $V \coprod V_E$? Why the disjoint union?

Comment: It don't think it matters in this case if the ordinary union or the disjoint union is used. $V$, the original vertices, and $V_E$, the added vertices, are already disjoint sets. For the edges it does matter, though I don't really like the notation of $E \coprod E$ for the new set of edges because the new edges are not really copies of the original ones. I suppose the new $i_E$ takes care of that.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Actually, I cannot understand what is $E\coprod E$. I am added an answer. Is correct?